# Annoying "expression result unused" warning

Tags: objective-c, xcode, if-statement

This is for a stupidly simple animation but I keep getting this annoying "expression result unused" warning. Code is as follows:

```
-(IBAction)thingOneTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender{
    if ((isLevel = YES)) {
        thingOneEnded = YES;
        goingToThingOne = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(otherThingToOne) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        x = 11;
        y = 118;
    }
    else (isLevel = NO); {
        [self viewDidLoad];
    }
}

-(void)otherThingToOne{
    if ((isLevel = YES) && (isLevelOne = YES)) {

        if ((x > 0) && (y > 0)) {
        otherThing.center = CGPointMake(otherThing.center.x - .5, otherThing.center.y - 5.35);
            x = x - .5;
            y = y - 5.35;
        }
        else ((x < 0) && (y < 0)); {
            [self levelOneDefault];
        // EVIL WARNING IS RIGHT HERE IN THE ELSE PART 
        }
    }
```

Comment: For checking equality you need to use == (i.e. Two equals signs) that's why you're getting the error. Also, your code will not work as you expect at the moment.

Comment: always the simple things haha thanks

Comment: Get rid of the semicolon at the end of the `else` line.

Comment: also there shouldn't be condition clause after `else`. If you want to use `else` with a condition, you must use `else if (condition)`.

Comment: You deleted your animation question. How is anyone going to help now? I couldn't post an answer when I commented and now I can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For checking equality you need to use `==` (i.e. Two equals signs) that's why you're getting the error. Also, your code will not work as you expect at the moment.

As mentioned by others.

Instead of using `if(someBool == YES)` just use `if(someBool)`. And instead of `if(someBool == NO)` just use `if(!someBool)`.

The reason it will not work at the moment is because (I think but not 100% on this) `if(someBool = NO)` will first set `someBool` to NO and then evaluate the condition which will always be `if(NO)` which will never enter the of block.

I think. But not sure about this as I haven't tested it.

Comment: You should not do `if (someBool == YES)`. Just do `if (someBool)`.

Comment: and `if (!someBool)` instead of `== NO`.

Comment: why won't it work as expected at the moment by the way?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use like that without checking `==` operator, also it will be more faster:-

```
if ((isLevel) && (isLevelOne))
```